# jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: '' Encountered "," at line 1, column 9

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file on a location from which i am reading the contents in a file. 
Thats why i have added Jmeter Bean shell Post processor and checking values of variable in debug sampler.

There is no error coming in sccript and thread is successfully getting executed and values are properly coming in variable.
Hiwever, in Jmeter logs, i am getting error -

> ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  In file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``Location,Advertiser,Product,Campaign,Supplier,Insertion order
>   ID,Invoice number, . . . '' Encountered "," at line 1, column 9.

I am having below code in my BeanShell PostProcessor -

```
${__FileToString(${InvoiceDataFile},UTF-8,CheckInvoice)}
```

`${InvoiceDataFile}` is a variable which i defined in the user defined variable and its value is the path of the directory where my CSV file is present.

eg: 
`${__P(includecontroller.prefix)}/Reporting/Prisma/Prisma US/properties/ReportsVerificationUS-${__P(test.environment)}/invoice_report.csv`

Please suggest.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Don't inline JMeter Variables like `${InvoiceDataFile}` or functions into Beanshell script body, they may resolve into something which will cause syntax errors. The correct Beanshell equivalent function will look like:

```
vars.put("CheckInvoice", org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(vars.get("InvoiceDataFile")),"UTF-8"));
```

Going forward you can take the next steps in order to get to the bottom of your Beanshell script failure:

1. Add [debug();](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive at the beginning of your script. This way you will be able to see debugging output in STDOUT
2. Put your code inside [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like

   ```
   try {
      //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Failed in Beanshell", ex);
      throw ex;
   }
   ```

   This way you will see a "good" error stacktrace in the *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter

Comment: Not sure what wrong is happening, but i am still facing the issue with the above code. Error - 2017/03/30 17:09:29 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``//Location,Advertiser,Product,Campaign,Supplier,Insertion order ID,Invoice numbe . . . '' Encountered "," at line 2, column 5.  Te only difference is previously it was coming on line 1 and now on line 2. Just FYI, My file has 2 rows and values in it as comma seperated